# High-accuracy time syncing between Android (Java) and .NET DateTime?

Tags: java, android, .net

I need a high accuracy time conversion between a native Android app and a .NET-based time stamp.

The .NET side simply uses:

```
long timeNowTicks = System.DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
```

And I need to match this .NET time stamp to within 5 minutes (3 billion ticks) on the Android side.  I can't change the .NET stuff.

I tried:

```
GregorianCalendar oldUtcTime = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
GregorianCalendar nowUtcTime = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
oldUtcTime.set(1,1,1,0,0,0); // .NET epoch
long utcTicks = 10000 * (nowUtcTime.getTimeInMillis() - oldUtcTime.getTimeInMillis()); // 10,000 ticks per ms
```

But this consistently gives me a number that is about 2.5 million seconds (~20 days) *behind* the DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.

[Some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949938/convert-date-between-java-and-net-2-days-off) are saying that this is because even though DateTime claims to adhere to the Gregorian Calendar, they don't actually skip the 10 days the Pope added to the calendar to fix it in the 1500's, but nowhere have I found a catch-all, formula-like conversion between the two.

How do I get ~5 minute accuracy between native Android time and .NET DateTime?

Comment: Use the actual date/time instead of ticks?  Why are you using ticks in the first place?

Comment: Not my decision.  Server guys wrote this .NET stuff and I'm trying to write an app that works with what they have.  Apparently changing it would be "a lot of work."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe `GregorianCalendar` does indeed observe the Julian/Gregorian cutover - although I note that you're setting `oldUtcTime` to the 1st of *February* in 1AD, which is probably why you're seeing a difference of 20 days instead of 10 days.

The simplest way to do this is to find out the Unix epoch in milliseconds using .NET - and then use that as a constant on the Java side:

```
// Handy method in .NET 4.6...
var unixEpoch = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(0);
Console.WriteLine(unixEpoch.Ticks / 10000L);
```

That gives an output of 62135596800000. So then you need:

```
private static final long BCL_MILLISECONDS_AT_UNIX_EPOCH = 62135596800000L;
private static final long TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND = 10000L;
...

long bclMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + BCL_MILLISECONDS_AT_UNIX_EPOCH;
long bclTicks = TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND * bclMillis;
```

Note that this isn't really "high accuracy" - it's only going to be as accurate as the system clock on each side. For really accurate time you'd need to use NTP or something similar. You could still find the two clocks are out by more than 5 minutes, just because clocks drift over time if they're not automatically corrected...

Comment: I guess I'm assuming the Android device clock and the server clock will be synced to the same standard clock.  This method works for now, but I view it as more of a workaround.  I.E. what happens when, say, daylight savings hits?  This wouldn't have maintainability in the future.

Comment: @Weikardzaena: Neither `System.currentTimeMillis()` nor `DateTime.UtcNow` are affected by time zones. I don't see what aspect you consider to be a "workaround".

Comment: First, I seemed rather ungrateful in my last comment.  Thank you for pointing out that I was messing up on the zero-based month thing.  I guess my concern was that this method depends on that offset from the .NET side staying constant.  If something were to change that number in the future, the only way to fix it on the app side would be to update this constant number.  I'd rather have something that is independent of some arbitrary conversion factor.  If it can't be done, I'll live with it.

Comment: @Weikardzaena: The number of ticks between the BCL epoch and the Unix epoch is a constant. It can't change, ever. It doesn't depend on time zones or anything else. This really is a non-issue.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.  I had it in my head that this was the number of ticks *to* the 1970 epoch, not from it.  That makes more sense.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Weikardzaena: It is - it's the number of seconds from the BCL epoch (which is fixed) to the 1970 epoch (which is also fixed). Neither of those is going to change. However, I still got the operator the wrong way round... will fix :)